# Cron jobs ended with 504 Gateway Timeout after 60s on GAE with python 3.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I created a  new project with google app engine using python 3.7 and django using [google template](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python37/django) .
All cron jobs failed with 504 request timeout. Also, I tried new  task queue
using google cloud tasks, but this request also failed after 60s.

App.yaml

```
# [START django_app]
runtime: python37

handlers:
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets/
- url: /.*
  script: auto

instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: automatic
```

Cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: cron eth price
  url: /cron/
  schedule: every 5 mins
```

Cron view

```
class CronView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        from time import sleep
        sleep(240)
        return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: Why does your cron task sleep for 4 minutes?

Comment: Just for example, Cron job should work for 10 minutes as I understand.

Comment: No ideas, I switched to the flexible environment

Answer (score 1):

This is just a theory :)

There seems to be a bit of a conflict in the documentation.

On one hand from (2nd generation standard environment) [Scheduling Jobs with cron.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml):

> A cron job will invoke a URL, using an HTTP `GET` request, at a given
>   time of day. An HTTP request invoked by cron can run for up to 60
>   minutes, but is [subject to the same limits as other HTTP
>   requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits).

By comparison, for the 1st generation standard environment, from [Deadlines](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cronref#deadlines):

> The cron timeout deadline depends on the instance class and scaling
>   type that is configured for your app:
>
> **Automatic scaling**
>
> Timeout is about 10 minutes.

On the other hand from the `Deadline` row in the [Instance scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling) table (consistent with [the 1st generation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#instance_scaling) info, but probably just a documentation bug given that the task queue support [is actually different](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#task_queue)):

> **Automatic scaling**
>
> 60-second deadline for HTTP requests, 10-minute deadline for task
>   queue tasks.

... and, of course, keeping in mind that the cron requests are HTTP requests, not task queue tasks.

Comment: Task queues are HTTP requests, so they fail after 60s too. But maybe you are right, it's some kind of bug.